# direct only sepcified requests to mod_jk balancer

Tags: apache, tomcat, xampp, mod-jk

i have created tomcat cluster,load balancing done by mod_jk module. i used xampp Apache as web server.
now all the request direct to the balancer. and i cannot access htdocts projects

what i need to do is sent only particular URL pattern to the Load balancer.
example
http//:localhost/sync/
all there requests followed by /sync/ should goes to balancer.

and all the other to htdocs (default scenario)
http//:localhost/

my /opt/lampp/apache2/conf/httpd.conf

```
Alias /bitnami/ "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs/"
Alias /bitnami "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs"

<Directory "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

LoadModule    jk_module  modules/mod_jk.so  

JkWorkersFile /opt/lampp/apache2/conf/workers.properties  

JkLogFile     logs/mod_jk.log  
JkLogLevel    emerg  
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "  
JkOptions     +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories  
JkRequestLogFormat     "%w %V %T"  

JkMount  /status  stat  
JkMount  /* balancer
```

i tried by changing

```
JkMount  /* balancer
```

to

```
JkMount  /sync/* balancer
```

by it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add no-jk for this particular URL

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "./particular_URL$" no-jk
```